# Replace only the last matched string with preg replace php

Tags: php, regex

I have this string :

```
use A\B\C;
use A\B\C;

var $foo;
/*
* comment
*/

use D\E\F;

Class Foo {
```

How i can replace the last string that beginning with use. In example above must be "use D\E\F;" as the result.

I have found many ways but no luck. including with lookahead negative (?!) but was confused how to use it. So this the i can get now " use(.*); " but this was replaced all the matched string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with `s` switch (DOTALL) for search:

```
'/use [^\n]*(?!.*?use)/s'
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dX9hQ9

**Code:**

```
$re = '/use [^\n]*(?!.*?use)/s'; 
$str = 'use A\B\C;
use A\B\C;
var $foo;
/*
* comment
*/
use D\E\F;
Class Foo {'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

#### Explanation:

- `s` modifier makes dot match new lines
- `use [^\n]*` matches text `use` untile new line is found
- `(?!.*?use)` is a **Negative Lookahead** which matches previous regex only if it is not followed by another `use`

Comment: can you explain it a bit more.. i will very apreciate it. btw thanks for the answer :) .

Comment: ahhh okay... i see the bottom of your link.. there is explanation there.. thanks ;)

Comment: Yes I added but regex101 has quite a detailed explanation.